# Test non ember data models with ember qunit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-qunit

I am using `ember-qunit` in an `ember-cli` application. My app is still not using `ember-data` for models.

The `moduleForModel` helper doesn't work at all. Is it required to have models extend from `DS.Model` to use `ember-qunit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the best part about testing simple models (without ember-data in the mix) is that you can new them up like plain old javascript objects.

```
import { test, module } from 'qunit';
import Foo from 'myapp/models/foo';

module('my first unit test');

test('do something with a computed property', function(assert) {
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.set('id', 1);
    foo.set('first', 'toran');
    foo.set('last', 'billups');
    //or this var foo = Foo.create({id: 1, first: 'toran', last: 'billups'});
    assert.equal(foo.get('full'), 'toran billups');
});
```

Comment: if you want to see some of this in action I did a meetup recently where I test drove a non ember-data setup from the ground up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5p7cg02hTs

Comment: I actually do something similar. My `model` mix in the `ember-validations` though. In order to test those, using `needs` is required https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations#testing which is obviously not present on the pojo's.

Comment: This should really be part of their documentation.